# text-overflow:ellipsis will not work when content is too short

Tags: html, css

A very simple question, but I haven't found answer.

there is a div with a text

```
<div class="hkb">Revenue</div>
```

the css is as follows:

```
.hkb{
    width: 28px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 11px;
    font-size: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then question comes:

1. change width value to 36px, the output shows  'R...', it's right, because the true width of 'Revenue' is 36px - 2*8px = 20px;
2. change width value to 28px, the output shows '...', it's also expected, 28 - 2*8 = 12;
3. change width value to 27 or below, the output will show 'Rev', the true width of 'Revenue' is 27px - 2*8px = 11px, maybe the width is not long enough to hold the text, **so it clips**.

what I want is to prevent clipping when the width of div becomes very short, I hope it can still shows '...'

here is the [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/zof2nrcs/).

Comment: Sounds like a browser quirk?  Your fiddle produces `'...'` in Chrome, at least.

Comment: Using Chrome (on my machine), it starts to clip under `24`, not `27` (here's a fiddle set to 23px http://jsfiddle.net/zof2nrcs/3/). I'm wondering if it has to do with the width of the `ellipsis` being greater than the containing element (if the containing element is less than the ellipsis, it displays the clipped text?)

Comment: yes, all I want to know is the threshold for ellipsis changing to clip in different browser, in different font-size, and some other factors

Answer (score 0):

text-overflow: ellipsis property required sum width please try it.

```
<body>
    <div class="hkb">Revenue</div>
</body>
.hkb{
        width: 40px;
        height: 15px;
        line-height: 11px;
        font-size: 8px;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        padding: 5px 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
         white-space: nowrap;

    }
```

Live **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/tyxc73ar/1/)**